# Which way that TAction has been fired?

Tags: delphi

There are a lot of ways how user can trigger an action (TAction) execution: shortcut keys, toolbar button, popup menu button etc. Is it possible to get information *how* that action has been triggered?

I'm just thinking about implementation of activity log to figure out the most popular ways to use different features in GUI.

**update**

I need to collect some stats about how an user interact with application GUI.

It's not the best idea to create a separate action for every button just because you need to implement logging. Ulrich Gerhardt's answer looks suitable. I can assign a handler to TActionList.OnExecute event and write log from one place.

Comment: If you want to know this your design is broken

Comment: I admire your telepathic ability to recognize an unknown application design.

Comment: If you want a button press to behave differently from a menu click, that's a different action.

Comment: It's not the best idea to create a separate action for every button just because you need implement logging. Ulrich Gerhardt's answer looks suitable. I can assign a handler to TActionList.OnExecute event and write log from one place.

Comment: I agree mostly with David, though he usually dramatizes things into a very black/white view. Often that helps a lot to explain things, but not everyone can appreciate it. TAction does not know what fired it, and that is by design. Usuaully you don't want to know what fired a TAction, but sometimes you do. Explain us why you need to know this, and we can help you get your design better.

Comment: @David: AFAICs, from the application's viewpoint the button and the menu item **do** initiate the same action. The difference between the two ways is not in the scope of the TAction system.

Comment: If you want to implement logging then you should probably do it at a lower level that the action handler.

Comment: @Jeroen As I have said I need to collect some stats about how an user interact with application GUI.

Comment: @David Do you have any ideas how that could be done?

Comment: @Roman: I typed this while you posted your comment. Please add that comment to your question, and I will drop my comment.

Comment: I'd probably intercept TMenu.Click, TButton.Click and TToolButton.Click.

Comment: Jeroen's right, I do tend to state my opinions in a very polarizing manner. Sorry.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you care whether they use the menus or the shortcuts? What you should be looking for is which actions are *invoked* most often and make sure you provide good keyboard access (e.g. shortuct) to those actions.

Comment: @David Perhaps you are right. I should think about this. Anyways, if some action in 95% was invoked by keyboard shortcut and only in 5% by a button on toolbar, that's might be a reason to hide the button by default in next relase.

Comment: Regarding collecting usage stats for your app, have a look at [DeskMetrics.com](http://www.deskmetrics.com).  It's a DLL and they have a Delphi interface unit.

Comment: @roman I guarantee that it will be the other way round. Button 95, shortcut 5!!

Comment: @David For example, I know at least 2 functions, which are invoked by shortcut MUCH often. Copy and Paste :)

Comment: that's true for power users. But for example MS Office statistics on copy and paste are quite interesting!

Comment: From [Jensen Harris's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jensenh/archive/2006/04/07/570798.aspx): What we didn't know until we analyzed the data was that even though so many people do use CTRL+V and do use "Paste" on the context menu, the toolbar button for Paste still gets clicked more than any other button. The command is so incredibly popular that even though there are more efficient ways of using it, many people do prefer to click the toolbar button.

Comment: @David Gathering this kind of detailed statistics is exactly what Microsoft was doing in Office for a while, and it is what prompted them to design the ribbon. The end result is debatable I'm sure, but the underlying intent is sound.

Comment: @mood ribbon is great, I can't use Office 2003 anymore!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you can use [ActionComponent](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TBasicAction_ActionComponent.html):

> Use ActionComponent to discern which
>   client component caused this action to
>   execute. For example, examine
>   ActionComponent from an OnExecute
>   event handler if you need to know what
>   user action triggered this action.
>
> When the user clicks a client control,
>   that client sets ActionComponent
>   before calling the action's Execute
>   method. After the action executes, the
>   action resets ActionComponent to nil
>   (Delphi) or NULL (C++).

There is also [TApplication.OnActionExecute](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_OnActionExecute.html), [TActionList.OnExecute](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ActnList_TActionList_OnExecute.html) and probably more "hooks".

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that property. It almost completely fits my needs. But what about shortcut keys? What value would be assigned to ActionComponent in this case?

Comment: Shortcut keys are not always bound to a component; Windows and/or Delphi can generate them for you. Explain us why you need this, and we can help you design your app in a better way.

Comment: Hard to detect the different ways an action could be invoked by keyboard. Could be shortcut. Could be accelerator. Could be navigation by cursor/tab keys.