# How to know which control was clicked when sharing an action?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tactionmanager

I'm implementing actions (in a `TActionManager`) for a user interface. Some controls, when clicked, execute the same action. However, in that action handler, I need to know which control was actually clicked by the user. But the `Sender` is a `TAction` instead of the originating control.

How can I identify which control using this action was actually pressed by the user?

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501123/which-way-that-taction-has-been-fired

Comment: @Toon That question seems to be more about menu, button or shortcut. But I expect there's a dupe somewhere! ;-)

Comment: Honestly what I'm doing is actually a menu item and a checkbox (toggling checked state back and forth at the same time) but the action execute handler is the same.

Comment: @Jerry - for a control, you've got an answer. But note that ActionComponent will be nil when the action is executed through an action menu item, as action menu items are not components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain this information from the [`ActionComponent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TBasicAction.ActionComponent) property of the action.